# CMake not throwing error when expected

Tags: cmake

My FindEigen.cmake is as follows:

```
find_path(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES Eigen/Core
  PATHS
  PATH_SUFFIXES eigen3
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../thirdparty
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/local/homebrew/include # Mac OS X
  /opt/local/var/macports/software # Mac OS X
  /opt/local/include
  /usr/include)

# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set EIGEN_FOUND to TRUE if 
# all listed variables are TRUE
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(EIGEN DEFAULT_MSG EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

This is called from my CMakeLists.txt file as follows:

```
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
```

The message I get back from the cmake gui is:

```
Could NOT find EIGEN (missing:  EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

but this is not an error and the configuration completes successfully. My understanding is that the REQUIRED option means that cmake should throw an error and halt if the package isn't found, and that the FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS method should enforce that. But this isn't happening for me. Any ideas why not?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem which was caused by the different naming used for the Eigen library in `find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)` and `find_package_handle_standard_args(EIGEN)`. E.g. you need to change `EIGEN` to `Eigen`.

Using the same naming in both places should fix this, along with the `REQUIRED_VARS` as suggested by @debris.

Answer (score 0):

try using [required_vars](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html)

```
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(EIGEN REQUIRED_VARS EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either. Furthermore, it doesn't check whether the package was actually required, in the call to find_package.